# Selenium FindBy Amazon Search Giving Error. (java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: java, selenium, method-call, findby

There is the Search Class where I made a method to do amazon search, and the Main Class calls the Method searchFor()
But I keep getting the error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
package Project1;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class Search {

    @FindBy(id = "twotabsearchtextbox")
    WebElement search_box;


    public void searchFor(String content) {
        search_box.sendKeys(content);
        search_box.submit();
    }



}
```

And this is the Main Class

```
package Project1;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Search s1 = new Search();

        s1.searchFor("gaming laptop");

    }
}
```

Comment: check if you initialized driver varibale properly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer below solution:

**Main class**

```
public class Main {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("Your url ");

            Search s1 = new Search(driver);
            s1.searchFor("gaming laptop");


    }
}
```

**Search class**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class Search {

    @FindBy(id = "twotabsearchtextbox")
    WebElement search_box;

    WebDriver driver;
    public Search(WebDriver driver){

        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

    }
    public void searchFor(String content) {

        search_box.sendKeys(content);
        search_box.submit();
    }

}
```